# class Test (in unnamed module @0x33f88ab) cannot access class com.sun.media.sound.FFT (in module java.desktop)

Tags: kotlin, fft

I want to use musicg to analysis audio fingerprint.
But I got following error in musicg library.

```
IllegalAccessError: class Test
(in unnamed module @0x33f88ab) cannot access class com.sun.media.sound.FFT
(in module java.desktop)
because module java.desktop does not export com.sun.media.sound to unnamed module @0x33f88ab
```

What should I do?

#### Environment

- Kotlin
- JDK 17(downgrade available)
- musicg 1.4.2.2

#### My code

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    FFT(10, 20)
}
```

got exception in `FFT(10, 20)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.sun` and its sub-packages are not part of the public Java API. They implement some standard Java APIs, but you shouldn't refer to them directly. (They're likely to change and/or be renamed or removed between JVM releases, and non-Sun/Oracle JVMs probably won't have them at all.)

In most cases you should access the public API classes (e.g. in `javax.sound`) instead. (Those may use `sun.*`/`com.sun.*`/etc. classes internally as needed, but that's merely an implementation detail.)

In early versions of Java, there was nothing to *stop* people using those internal implementation classes, and so some developers got into bad habits. But Java 9 added a [module system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System), which restricts access to them. The error message you see is a result of that.

The details are in [JEP 260](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/260). The intent was that there would be public APIs for all of the critical APIs that were being restricted. However, according to [this Oracle forum page](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4055827/com-sun-media-sound-in-java-9), the work wasn't completed, and so there are some internal APIs for which no public equivalent exists yet.

`FFT` looks like one of those classes that has been overlooked. I can't see a direct replacement for it, I'm afraid. Is there a third-party library you can use? [This question](/questions/3287518/reliable-and-fast-fft-in-java) gives some options.